# String Element of Struct not retaining assigned value

Tags: c, string, struct

I'm having a bit of a bizarre issue with C.

I have a `.c` file implementing a structure, and another using it. The structure in question is basic info about a student (name and grade). The Implementation file has the functions

- initialize
- read name
- read grade
- free memory (delete instance)

the main file goes as follows:

```
int main (void){
    char inBuff[30];
    char* name = NULL;
    int grade;
    Student Stu;

    printf("main: Please enter the name\n");
    fgets(inBuff, 30, stdin);
    name = malloc((sizeof(char)+1)*strlen(inBuff));
    strncpy (name, inBuff, 20);

    printf("main: Please enter the grade\n");
    scanf("%d", &grade);

    InitializeStudent (name, grade, &Stu);

    /*value testing*/
    printf("main: %s\n", Stu.name);
    printf("main: %d\n", Stu.grade);

    printf ("main: The student's name is %s\n", NameOfStudent(Stu));
    printf ("main: The student's grade is %d\n", GradeOfStudent(Stu));

    FreeStudent(&Stu);
    free (name);
    return 0;
}
```

`printf()` statements in the `InitializeStudent()` function seem to show the values being assigned correctly. However, both `Stu.name` and `NameOfStudent(Stu)` return `ASCII`, and `Stu.Grade` and `GradeOfStudent(Stu)` return `2675716` (which seems to be a memory address) regardless of input.

Of note is the fact that it has been specified that `NameOfStudent()` and `GradeOfStudent()` be pass-by-value rather than using a pointer (ie a copy of the struct should be made and passed in to the functions) and have `char*` and `int` return types respectively, whereas `InitializeStudent()` is passed a pointer and is a void function.

Also possibly important, the name field of Student is initialized as

```
char name[20];
```

rather than

```
char* name;
```

the `Student` struct definition is as follows:

```
#define MAXNAMESIZE 20
typedef struct {
    char name[MAXNAMESIZE];
    int grade;
} Student;
```

as requested, the code for initialize student is as follows

```
void InitializeStudent (char *name, int grade, Student *S) {
    printf ("InitializeStudent: entered initialization\n");
    int i = 0;
    S = malloc (sizeof(Student));
    for (i = 0; i< strlen(name); i++)
        if (name[i] == '\n')
            name[i] = '\0';
    strncpy(S->name, name, 20);
    S->grade = grade;

    printf ("InitializeStudent: %s\n", S->name);
    printf ("InitializeStudent: %d\n", S->grade);
}
```

Comment: Please consider indenting your code, and adding the declaration of `struct Student`. EDIT: right, I noticed the code is indented except you're using tabs. For SO it's better to convert the indentation to spaces in your editor before posting.

Comment: Also possibly important is to provide us `NameOfStudent` and `GradeOfStudent` implementations.

Comment: Please show the code for `InitializeStudent (name, grade, &Stu)`

Comment: The expression `(sizeof(char)+1)*strlen(inBuff)` allocates almost twice what you need. First thing to remember is that `sizeof(char)` is *always* `1`. Knowing that, you should also know that then it's  enough to only allocate `strlen(...) + 1` bytes. And in this case it might not even be needed to allocate that string, hard to tell until you show the `InitializeStudent` function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That whole `malloc()` call and the following `strncpy()` seem unnecessary to begin with, since `InitializeStudent()` has no choice but to copy the value of the `name` parameter into the struct member.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you allocate the `Student` structure in the `InitializeStudent` function, when you pass it a pointer to an already allocated structure.

And because arguments are passed by value (i.e. copied) to functions, the pointer `S` is a copy, so when you assign to it you only assign to your local copy in the function. That is why the structure in the `main` function is not initialized, because you only initialize the structure you allocate in the `InitializeStudent` function, not the one you pass in.

And lastly, be careful with `strncpy` as if the source string is longer than the length you pass to it, then the function will *not* add the string terminator.

---

Oh and by the way, there is a simpler way of removing the newline from `fgets`: Just "remove" the last character:

```
/* If `name` is not a `NULL` pointer, and the length is larger than zero
 * and the last character is a newline...
 */
if (name != NULL && strlen(name) > 0 && name[strlen(name) - 1] == '\n')
    name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Is the structure allocated when I first declare it? Otherwise, the only allocation is for the string "name" used in input.

Also, as far as I was aware, passing a pointer to a function was C's way of imitating pass-by-reference and using the -> should allow me to initialize the original struct?

Comment: @user2824330 Yes, everything declared as a non-pointer is already allocated. It doesn't matter if it's native types (like `int`) or structures.

Comment: alright, removing the malloc in InitializeStudent seems to work.

Comment: Re. the "simpler way", at least the OP's version of that doesn't invoke UB when the string is empty

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Lol. I think it's more or less a given that the OP is already struggling to understand things as it is?